# App crash when tabbed activity slide back to first tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, mobile, android-asynctask

I created tabbed activity by standard method built into android studio. Each tab contains two sub-fragments - first fragment have spinners, depending on the choice of which is put right the nested fragment. The tabs are normally slide from first to last (4 tabs). Between the first and second tabs slide perfectly, and between 3 and 4 is also normal switches. But if i try to slide from 3 or 4 back to the 1st or 2nd tab, the application crash, always blame on a nested fragment in the first tab, even if the slide was from 3rd to 2nd tab. What's wrong?

Switching between tabs in TabActivity

```
switch(position){
                case 0:
                    Fragment addNewFragment = new AddNew_fragment();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("connectURL", connectURL);
                    args.putString("access_token", access_token);
                    addNewFragment.setArguments(args);
                    return addNewFragment;
                case 1:
                    Fragment toDoListFragment = new ToDoListFragment();
                    Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
                    args1.putString("connectURL", connectURL);
                    args1.putString("access_token", access_token);
                    toDoListFragment.setArguments(args1);
                    return toDoListFragment;
                case 2:
                    Fragment allNewsFragment = new AllNewsFragment();
                    Bundle args2 = new Bundle();
                    args2.putString("connectURL", connectURL);
                    args2.putString("access_token", access_token);
                    allNewsFragment.setArguments(args2);
                    return allNewsFragment;
                case 3:
                    Fragment myPageFragment = new MyPageFragment();
                    Bundle args3 = new Bundle();
                    args3.putString("connectURL", connectURL);
                    args3.putString("access_token", access_token);
                    myPageFragment.setArguments(args3);
                    return myPageFragment;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
```

Nested fragment on 1st tab

```
public class GoalsListFragment extends ListFragment {

    int goalID;
    int goalExist;

    JSONObject jsonResponseReports = null;
    JSONObject jsonResponse;
    JSONArray items;

    String goalDescriptionText;


    StringBuilder feedInput;

    String connectURL;

    ArrayList<String> allGoalsList;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        connectURL = getArguments().getString("connectURL");
        View goalFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_goals_list, null);

        allGoalsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        new GetAllGoals().execute();

        return goalFragment;
    }



    private class GetAllGoals extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(connectURL);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
                connection.setDoInput(true);


                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                feedInput = new StringBuilder();

                String inputBufferSymbol = "";

                while ((inputBufferSymbol = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    feedInput.append(inputBufferSymbol);
                }
                br.close();


                jsonResponseReports = new JSONObject(feedInput.toString());
                jsonResponse = jsonResponseReports.getJSONObject("response");
                if (jsonResponse.getString("count").equals("0")) {
                    goalDescriptionText = "В этой сфере жизни вы не поставили ни одной цели";
                    goalExist = 0;
                } else {
                    goalExist = 1;

                    items = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");

                    int count=0;

                    while (count<Integer.parseInt(jsonResponse.getString("count")))
                    {
                        allGoalsList.add(items.getJSONObject(count).getString("title"));
                        count++;
                    }
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, allGoalsList);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Always blame on adapter in onPostExecute

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, allGoalsList);
```

> 09-21 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim D/AndroidRuntime:
> Shutting down VM 09-21 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim
> W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
> (group=0xb2cd8908) 09-21 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-21 18:07:56.920
> 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime:
> java.lang.NullPointerException 09-21 18:07:56.920
> 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310) 09-21
> 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> android.widget.ArrayAdapter.(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
>
> **09-21 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at fragments.GoalsListFragment$GetAllGoals.onPostExecute(GoalsListFragment.java:122)
> 09-21 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at fragments.GoalsListFragment$GetAllGoals.onPostExecute(GoalsListFragment.java:63)**
>
> 09-21 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631) 09-21 18:07:56.920
> 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) 09-21 18:07:56.920
> 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
> 09-21 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-21 18:07:56.920
> 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-21 18:07:56.920
> 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 09-21
> 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-21
> 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-21 18:07:56.920
> 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
> 09-21 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 09-21
> 18:07:56.920 1729-1729/im.upgrade.upgradeim E/AndroidRuntime: at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging to see if getActivity() is null, or allGoalList

My guess is the fragment is being disposed of and one of these is null.

You should check for non null everytime in you application try this

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) 
    {
        if(null != getActivity() )
        {
           if(null != allGoalsList){ // log to find error}
           adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, allGoalsList);
           setListAdapter(adapter);
         }
    }
```

Comment: getActivity(). But later i replace your code just with   if (isAdded()) {}